# How to change a error message into a warning message in pylint?

Tags: pylint, pylintrc

Is there a way to change/specify the severity level (error, warning) of a rule in pylintrc file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that this is not possible at the moment.
There is an existing [feature request at github](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2293).